State is always being set to Texas?
Magento 2.4.6-p3
I am hiding the state option in checkout and for those cases where the customer does not have to select a state, the state is always set to "Texas".
I did not find a setting where some default value is set to Texas. What could be the reason?
Thanks

How you hide that options? Before hiding what option show on the list?

Magento 2 does not provide a direct option to set a default state in the Admin panel.
We have to set it programmatically.
The easiest way to set the default state value is from the js script below:
jQuery("select[name='region_id'] option[value='57']").prop('selected', true);
This will set the default state to Texas where 57 is the state option value of Texas.
You can include this script in your js file and load it on checkout page. This is the hardcoded way.
